# How to click on the element as per the HTML which is within a modal box through Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm automating some website in which I need to log out. I'm facing a hard time in this code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, 10);
WebElement Category_Body = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("user logout")));
Category_Body.click();
d.findElement(By.id("logout_user")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

HTML:

```
<a class="user logout" title="Sign out" data-target="#confirm_popup" data-toggle="modal"></a>
```

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"user logout"}
```

Comment: is it in `iframe` ?

Comment: I also tried different ways to address this error. Not working , kind share your views .

Comment: @NarendraR  Its not in iframe

Comment: Use By.class('user') or By.cssSelector('.user.logout')

Comment: @DakshinamurthyKarra sry this is also not working

Comment: @sara still same error?

Comment: @sara : Is there any text between anchor tags ?

Comment: no text between the anchor tag

Comment: Does it help my answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code for that:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, 10);
WebElement Category_Body = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".user.logout")));
Category_Body.click();
```

PS: You can do this with `ExpectedCondition.elementToBeClickable`, also.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the identifier 
You have used

```
    WebElement Category_Body = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("user logout")));
```

But according to your HTML

```
<a class="user logout" title="Sign out" data-target="#confirm_popup" data-toggle="modal"></a>
```

The link have no id called "**User Logout**"
With out using id try to use class `By.findElementByClassName("user logout")`

As a Second solution, try to use xpath ( which will work most of the time )

If both the solutions are not usable you can use the JavascriptExecutor ( The elements which are hard to capture can be easily handled with JavascriptExecutor  )

**NOTE:** The main issue is with you using "user logout" when there is no such ID

Cheers

Comment: `By.class("user logout")` searches for a element with class 'user logout' and not for an element that has classes 'user' and 'logout'.

Comment: Sorry it should be 
By.findElementByClassName("user logout")

Comment: I tried absolute and dynamic xpath , class still not working

Comment: It could be due to wait time being not enough. Try to increase the wait to maybe 60 sec. ( Not sure if it's going to work )
And How did you extracted the XPath? ( If you have the IDE you can use it to identify different selectors for an element )

Comment: When an attribute class is given a value "user logout" - the element is deemed to have two classes - 'user' and 'logout'. Not a single class name "user logout".

Comment: If the spacing in between created the issue, you may use one of these (hopefully it should work) (By.xpath("//a[@class='user logout']")) or By.cssSelector("a[class='user logout']")

Answer (score 0):

As per your to locate the desired element to *logout* within the *Model Box* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the the following options:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.user.logout[title='Sign out'][data-toggle='modal']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='user logout' and @title='Sign out'][@data-toggle='modal']"))).click();
  ```